# Really fancy printing on python

Tags: python, text

Since python has  way to do nearly everything I was wondering is there any API which would help me print out really fancy text to my log e.g.

```
#   # ####### #        #         ##########
#   # #       #        #         #        #
#   # #       #        #         #        #
##### ####    #        #         #        #
#   # #       #        #         #        #
#   # #       #        #         #        #
#   # ####### ######## ########  ##########
```

I have tried pprint and there is nothing in it like this.

Any tips?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a Python recipe that does just that: [Banner](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577537-banner/).

On some systems, there also exists a [`banner`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/6/banner/) command:

```
aix@aix:~$ banner HELLO
#     # ####### #       #       #######
#     # #       #       #       #     #
#     # #       #       #       #     #
####### #####   #       #       #     #
#     # #       #       #       #     #
#     # #       #       #       #     #
#     # ####### ####### ####### #######
```

Comment: Super answer.  And if anyone is looking for it to run the sys command, it's import os and then os.system('banner Hello')

Answer (score 2):

## Fancy text in Python Console.

You could try `PyFiglet` => https://pypi.org/project/pyfiglet/0.7/

##### Simple example:-

```
import pyfiglet
text = pyfiglet.format("Pyfiglet test")
print(text)
```

Please click [HERE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ascii-art-using-pyfiglet-module/) to find more...

---

Reference :- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ascii-art-using-pyfiglet-module/

Answer (score 1):

## Stylish text

You could use the art Python library for this.
Link for the library - [Link](https://pypi.org/project/art/).

Simple example

```py
from art import text2art
a = text2art("Text")
print(a)
```

Reference - [Link](https://pypi.org/project/art/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need APIs to print fancy text. Just go to https://fsymbols.com/generators/tarty/ . Type your text and copy it. Then open your Python file and your code should be :

```py
print("""

██╗░░░██╗░█████╗░██╗░░░██╗██████╗░  ████████╗███████╗██╗░░██╗████████╗  ██╗░░██╗███████╗██████╗░███████╗
╚██╗░██╔╝██╔══██╗██║░░░██║██╔══██╗  ╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝╚██╗██╔╝╚══██╔══╝  ██║░░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔════╝
░╚████╔╝░██║░░██║██║░░░██║██████╔╝  ░░░██║░░░█████╗░░░╚███╔╝░░░░██║░░░  ███████║█████╗░░██████╔╝█████╗░░
░░╚██╔╝░░██║░░██║██║░░░██║██╔══██╗  ░░░██║░░░██╔══╝░░░██╔██╗░░░░██║░░░  ██╔══██║██╔══╝░░██╔══██╗██╔══╝░░
░░░██║░░░╚█████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║░░██║  ░░░██║░░░███████╗██╔╝╚██╗░░░██║░░░  ██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║███████╗
░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝  ░░░╚═╝░░░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░  ╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝
""")
```