# How to easily print ascii-art text?

Tags: python, user-interface, text, command-line, logging

I have a program that dumps a lot of output, and **I want some of that output to really stand out**. One way could be to **render important text with ascii art**, like [this web service](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/) does for example:

```
 #    #   ##   #####  #    # # #    #  ####  
 #    #  #  #  #    # ##   # # ##   # #    # 
 #    # #    # #    # # #  # # # #  # #      
 # ## # ###### #####  #  # # # #  # # #  ### 
 ##  ## #    # #   #  #   ## # #   ## #    # 
 #    # #    # #    # #    # # #    #  ####
```

**other solutions could be colored or bold output**. So how to do this sort of stuff easily in Python?

Comment: You could call out to figlet, a unix utility.

Comment: @Marcin: thanks, figlet seems nice! Some people even seem to have implemented python wrappers for it.

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to answer your own question with your further information on that.

Comment: Here you have figlet port in pure python: https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet

Comment: don't know figlet, (which sounds better), but what you describe in your question is exactly like the output of `banner`. Good luck.

Comment: try dis - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70863752/17761216

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72173699/17761216

Answer (score 109, accepted):

- pyfiglet - pure Python implementation of http://www.figlet.org

  ```
  pip install pyfiglet
  ```
- termcolor - helper functions for ANSI color formatting

  ```
  pip install termcolor
  ```
- colorama - multiplatform support (Windows)

  ```
  pip install colorama
  ```

```
import sys

from colorama import init
init(strip=not sys.stdout.isatty()) # strip colors if stdout is redirected
from termcolor import cprint 
from pyfiglet import figlet_format

cprint(figlet_format('missile!', font='starwars'),
       'yellow', 'on_red', attrs=['bold'])
```

#### Example

```
$ python print-warning.py
```

[image: missile]

```
$ python print-warning.py | cat
.___  ___.  __       _______.     _______. __   __       _______  __
|   \/   | |  |     /       |    /       ||  | |  |     |   ____||  |
|  \  /  | |  |    |   (----`   |   (----`|  | |  |     |  |__   |  |
|  |\/|  | |  |     \   \        \   \    |  | |  |     |   __|  |  |
|  |  |  | |  | .----)   |   .----)   |   |  | |  `----.|  |____ |__|
|__|  |__| |__| |_______/    |_______/    |__| |_______||_______|(__)
```

Comment: +1 For the big a*s Missile warning! :)

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: If you've been hit by a missile then your eyes might not be the only thing that is burning.

Answer (score 37):

PIL gives a cool way to do this very simple.
You can render the text onto a b/w image and convert that bitmap to a string stream replacing the black and white pixels to chars.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

ShowText = 'Python PIL'

font = ImageFont.truetype('arialbd.ttf', 15) #load the font
size = font.getsize(ShowText)  #calc the size of text in pixels
image = Image.new('1', size, 1)  #create a b/w image
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0, 0), ShowText, font=font) #render the text to the bitmap
for rownum in range(size[1]): 
#scan the bitmap:
# print ' ' for black pixel and 
# print '#' for white one
    line = []
    for colnum in range(size[0]):
        if image.getpixel((colnum, rownum)): line.append(' '),
        else: line.append('#'),
    print ''.join(line)
```

It renders the next result:

```
 #######                 ##                              #######   ##  ##
 ##   ###           ##   ##                              ##   ###  ##  ##
 ##    ##           ##   ##                              ##    ##  ##  ##
 ##    ## ##    ## ####  ######     ####    ######       ##    ##  ##  ##
 ##    ##  ##  ###  ##   ###  ##   ##  ##   ###  ##      ##    ##  ##  ##
 ##   ##   ##  ##   ##   ##   ##  ##    ##  ##   ##      ##   ##   ##  ##
 ######    ##  ##   ##   ##   ##  ##    ##  ##   ##      ######    ##  ##
 ##         ## #    ##   ##   ##  ##    ##  ##   ##      ##        ##  ##
 ##         ####    ##   ##   ##  ##    ##  ##   ##      ##        ##  ##
 ##         ####    ##   ##   ##   ##  ##   ##   ##      ##        ##  ##
 ##          ##     ###  ##   ##    ####    ##   ##      ##        ##  ########
             ##
             ##
           ###             
         ##
       ###
```

I made a little more comprehensive example with functional style.

```
import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

ShowText = 'Python PIL'


font = ImageFont.truetype('arialbd.ttf', 15) #load the font
size = font.getsize(ShowText)  #calc the size of text in pixels
image = Image.new('1', size, 1)  #create a b/w image
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0, 0), ShowText, font=font) #render the text to the bitmap

def mapBitToChar(im, col, row):
    if im.getpixel((col, row)): return ' '
    else: return '#'

for r in range(size[1]):
    print ''.join([mapBitToChar(image, c, r) for c in range(size[0])])
```

Answer (score 13):

This is fun. I've figured out how to use PIL (the "Pillow" fork, of course) and Numpy to do this fully "vectorized", i.e. without loops:

```py
text = "Hi there"
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import numpy as np
myfont = ImageFont.truetype("verdanab.ttf", 12)
size = myfont.getbbox(text)[2:]
img = Image.new("1",size,"black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0), text, "white", font=myfont)
pixels = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
chars = np.array([' ','#'], dtype="U1")[pixels]
strings = chars.view('U' + str(chars.shape[1])).flatten()
print( "\n".join(strings))
```

```
           ##           ##                            
 ##    ##  ##      ##   ##                            
 ##    ##          ##   ##                            
 ##    ##  ##     ##### #####    ####   ## ##  ####   
 ##    ##  ##      ##   ##  ##  ##  ##  ##### ##  ##  
 ########  ##      ##   ##  ##  ##  ##  ##    ##  ##  
 ##    ##  ##      ##   ##  ##  ######  ##    ######  
 ##    ##  ##      ##   ##  ##  ##      ##    ##      
 ##    ##  ##      ##   ##  ##  ##   #  ##    ##   #  
 ##    ##  ##       ### ##  ##   ####   ##     ####
```