# how to make pyramid python like that..?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to make program like this.???

Input : 4

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 * * * *
```

I would love to know how to do this, it's been bugging me all week but it was only an extra credit question so my teacher never explained how to do it!! :(
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlyGu.jpg

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried so far?

Comment: related: [ASCII art in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13076194/4279) (there is an answer that uses `print()` once to print the pattern).

Comment: Please show your efforts, we're not here to solve homeworks.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be fun to try, here is my solution:

```
PROMPT_MSG = "Please enter a whole number, greater than 1"
PROMPT_MSG_ERR = "Oops! Please try again.."

def validate_input(input):
    try:
        assert int(input) > 1
        return int(input)

    except (ValueError, AssertionError) as e:
        print PROMPT_MSG_ERR + "\n"
        main()

def main():
    user_input = raw_input("{0}: ".format(PROMPT_MSG))
    valid_input = validate_input(user_input)

    if valid_input:
        print "{0}*".format(" " * valid_input)
        for i in range(0, valid_input)[1:-1]:     
            print "{0}*{1}*".format(
                (" " * (valid_input - i)),
                (" " * (i + (i-1))),
            )
        print " *" * valid_input

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```