# getting the bitmask of a text string in python

Tags: python, numpy, cairo, raster

I am reading this tutorial on [word-clouds](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.com/2012/11/a-wordcloud-in-python.html) and it requires the shapes of rasterized strings.   Then one could compute intersections of the word shapes with [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).

The author in the tutorial complains about [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).  A more direct way, might be using [`pyCairo`](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/).  However, I couldn't not get the find the bitmask corresponding to each glyphs.

Ideally, I would like to input **1** and return some collection of 1's and zeros, that I can put into numpy.

```
0000011100000
0000111100000
0001111100000
0000011100000
0000011100000
0000011100000
0000011100000
0000011100000
1111111111111
1111111111111
```

Here is my attempt with Cairo, but I can't get the bitmask out of Cairo or draw it or anything else:

```python
import cairo as cr
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 256, 256

surface = cairo.ImageSurface (cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
ctx = cairo.Context (surface)

ctx.set_source_rgb(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
ctx.select_font_face("Georgia", cairo.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, cairo.FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD)
ctx.set_font_size(1.2)
x_bearing, y_bearing, width, height = ctx.text_extents("a")[:4]
ctx.move_to(0.5 - width / 2 - x_bearing, 0.5 - height / 2 - y_bearing)
ctx.show_text("a")
```

---

In fact, any reliable way of getting ascii representations of numbers might be appropriate.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632995/is-there-a-python-library-that-allows-to-easily-print-ascii-art-text

Comment: You can start to debug this by using surface write_to_png  to check the output is what you think it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to binary in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After running your above code, you can convert the rendered letter to a numpy boolean array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.frombuffer(surface.get_data(), dtype=np.int32)
bitmask = (ar.reshape(WIDTH, HEIGHT) != 0)
```

You can verify that it worked by displaying the resulting array with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(bitmask)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that this needs a few edits to your code that I made (but that have not yet been through the review): you did not use the imported cairo as `cr` (I replaced it by a simple `import cairo`), the font size was much too small (I replaced it by 200), and in the `move_to` you have to use `WIDTH/2` and `HEIGHT/2` instead of 0.5 .

Comment: So in fact the edits have been rejected, I should have just added the changes as a comment.