# Does anyone have any advice on how to get this started? I am at a stand still

Tags: loops, python-3.x, nested-lists, horizontallist

File: banner.py
Date: 12/6/15 
Purpose: To write a program that prints a sideways banner.
The characters A-Z and .,!?& are in a file in a seven line by whatever
width necessary. Each text is separated by a blank from the next letter Ex.)             ###
       ## ##
      ##   ##
     ##     ##
     #########
     ##     ##
     ##     ## 
    # so the letter A has to be flipped and produced horizontally. 
    # so if "yum" was entered as a phrase, it would print "yum" sideways

```
def main(): 

    print("Program to print a sideways banner.")     
    print("The letters and specials are in a file")     
    print("You will be asked to enter the name of a file.")     
    print("Written by John Doe")     
    fileName = input(Enter the name of a file: ")     
    print()     
    phrase = ("Enter phrase to print: ")
```

Comment: the hashtags should be in the form of the letter A.

Comment: You didn't do any work. You might have just posted a "Hello World" program and asked us to implement Google's search engine for you.

Comment: Not asking someone to do it, need help getting it started. I am not very good, clearly

Answer (score 0):

To get started, check out [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632995/is-there-a-python-library-that-allows-to-easily-print-ascii-art-text) question/answers. See what you can get out from that, play around with the code, do some research. And maybe check out the answers to [this programming puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51716/print-input-sideways) to get some ideas. Good luck :)