# Layout images in form of a number

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a folder with small images (Facebook profile pictures). I want to make a new mosaic-like picture where all the small pictures are laid out in the form of a number, like in this example ([source](https://theamt.com/800_member_milestone_reached.htm)).

[image]

Is there a software program that can do this (and that runs on Windows 7)? 
Otherwise I'm also open to writing a small script to do the same. 
I know how I can add a white border to the images with PIL/Pillow, but my searches for how to layout the images have turned up fruitless.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could have a look at the parts relating to masking in this [wordcloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/wordcloud/wordcloud.py) repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsheperd shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27753869/190597) how to convert text into ASCII art. You can modify that code slightly to obtain a glyph mask -- 1 where the font is black, and 0 where there is background. We can then use PIL to randomly rotate and paste a face wherever the mask is 1.

Below I used `matplotlib` just to obtain an image (of Ada Lovelace) that we would all have assuming you have `matplotlib` installed. You can remove the matplotlib dependency and just redefine `faces` to be a sequence of PIL images.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

def text_to_pixels(text, path='arialbd.ttf', fontsize=14):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/27753869/190597 (jsheperd)
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/36386628/190597 (unutbu)
    """
    font = ImageFont.truetype(path, fontsize) 
    w, h = font.getsize(text)  
    h *= 2
    image = Image.new('L', (w, h), 1)  
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.text((0, 0), text, font=font) 
    arr = np.asarray(image)
    arr = np.where(arr, 0, 1)
    arr = arr[(arr != 0).any(axis=1)]
    return arr

def get_image():
    fn = cbook.get_sample_data("ada.png")
    face_img = Image.open(fn).convert('RGBA')
    face_img = face_img.resize((30, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # give image a white background
    img = Image.new('RGBA', size=(36, 46), color=(255, 255, 255))
    img.paste(face_img, (3, 3))
    return img

def sqdist(a, b):
    return ((a -b)**2).sum()

def pics_in_text(text, faces, img_width=600, img_height=250, path='arialbd.ttf', 
                 fontsize=20, minsep=1000):
    arr = text_to_pixels(text, path=path, fontsize=fontsize)
    yx = np.column_stack(np.where(arr)).astype(float) 
    yx /= arr.shape
    yx *= (0.75, 0.90)
    yx += 0.05
    yx *= (img_height, img_width)
    yx = yx.astype('int')
    np.random.shuffle(yx)
    keep = []
    for coord in yx:
        if all(sqdist(item, coord) > minsep for item in keep):
            keep.append(coord)
    yx = IT.cycle(keep)

    img = Image.new('RGBA', size=(img_width, img_height), color=(255, 255, 255, 255))
    seen = list()
    for face, coord in zip(faces, yx):
        deg = np.random.uniform(-45, 45)
        face = face.rotate(deg, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=False)
        img.paste(face, tuple(coord[::-1]), mask=face)
    return img

def get_image():
    import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
    fn = cbook.get_sample_data("ada.png")
    face_img = Image.open(fn).convert('RGBA')
    face_img = face_img.resize((30, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # give image a white background
    img = Image.new('RGBA', size=(36, 46), color=(255, 255, 255))
    img.paste(face_img, (3, 3))
    return img

num_faces = 650
faces = IT.islice(IT.cycle([get_image()]), num_faces)
img = pics_in_text('800', faces, img_width=1200, img_height=500, 
             path='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf', 
             fontsize=40, minsep=375)
img.save('/tmp/out.png', 'PNG')
```

[image]

`min_sep` is the minimum squared distance between face images. If you increase the `min_sep` parameter, the faces will be spaced farther apart. If you decrease `min_sep` then the faces may overlap more densely.