# How to print a text as a "big ascii" text art using bash script that runs on windows

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, ascii, figlet

I have a bash `test.sh` script that does execute some commands when executed in windows-cmd.

I'm literally trying to display some text at the begining in something like ASCII text format. After long searching i came to `figlet` which seems to be very straight forward on linux. However, the bash script is executed on windows-cmd. I found a version of `figlet` for python: [How to easily print ascii-art text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632995/how-to-easily-print-ascii-art-text)

However, i just want to simply integrate figlet in my `test.sh` script and execute this on windows.

So how to get figlet work from command line (and not through python) **on windows** ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on your setup. *"`bash script is executed on windows-cmd`"*. How do you do this? Usually a bash script shouldn't be able to run in windows cmd. Are you using something like WSL? If so, then install figlet inside that environment. Otherwise, if you are using only windows cmd, install figlet for windows. The official site offers a binary for windows: http://ftp.figlet.org/pub/figlet/program/windows/

Comment: @Socowi. thanks for the comment. Perhaps it would be better to call it shell script so that its is now understod that i run it on windows?. Regarding the figlet link you posted, is this a GUI or can i execute it from command line when for example typing "figlet something"?. Besides the website seems to be not secured! –

Comment: @Socowi I've tried to download the files linked in the link and followed the readme file. it seems its not straight forward on windows. Have you installed it before on windows?

Comment: Sorry, as a Linux user I didn't try this on windows. Luckily, there is already a question about the installation of figlet on windows on superuser.com: [Figlets installation on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1361312/652023).

Comment: Thanks. If you would post it as an answer. I would gladly accept it